# CSS: box-shadow on four sides with blur effect

Tags: css, box-shadow

I'm trying to get `box-shadow` on all 4 sides of my element.

I've tried `box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 4px 5px grey` but it doesn't work.  There also doesn't seem to be a rule for specifically setting the blur of a `box-shadow`.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid properties. Even if it is, you should try a simple [mcve] first and show that to us. Why not use the simplest form of the property or inspect/debug it using any browser developer tools. https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have googled this a bit more, you would have found the answer right away.

The `box-shadow` property syntax is the fallowing :

> **box-shadow : horizontal offset | vertical offset | blur | spread | color ;**

So you want it on all sides means :

1. No offsets.
2. Blur as you like.

Spread here is key to this, setting `10px` to the spread means `5px` on all sides, basically, half the amount will be on each facing side.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px grey;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Also if you want to customize that you always define multiple shadows separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead `5px` specify the blur distance of the shadow while `10px` specify the horizontal and vertical shadow of the box-shadow. You can check this link for more info https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_shadows.asp

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div>This is a div element with a box-shadow</div>

</body>
```

or

you can modify yours like so 
`box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px grey`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra value to `box-shadow` property. This works: `box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 5px grey`

Answer (score 0):

To get a box-shadow on all sides of your element, you'll need:

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: lawngreen;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
```

```html
<div>All of my sides have a box-shadow!</div>
```